# Test the status code of a real request to an API with Jest

Tags: javascript, rest, api, jestjs

Hello I'm trying to test this API call but I don't know how to test for the status code of the response since it is a real (and it has to stay like that) API call and not a mock one

this is the function I'm testing:

```js
export const getDataFromApi = (url) => {
  return axios.get(url)
    .then(({ data }) => data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err.toString()));
}
```

and this is the test:

```js
describe('Read data from API', () => {
  test('Get result of the API call', (done) => {
    const apiUrl = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character";
    getDataFromApi(apiUrl)
      .then(data => {
        expect(data).toBeDefined();
        expect(data.results.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

how can I expect if the status code of data is 200 or if is another status code?

also is necessary for me to leave that `done` after the execution of the function? I know with call backs I have to put it but with this promise I'm not sure

Comment: I didn't see the code assert the status code

Comment: the status code is what I want to test to check if I get 200 or other code @slideshowp2

Answer (score 2):

Axios has a [single response object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) returned in both the success and error paths which contains the HTTP status code. An [error is raised if the response is not in the 2xx range](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors).

You can plumb the status code as a return object from your `getDataFromApi()` wrapper function, but you'll probably want the full response object for other checks (like headers). I recommend getting rid of the wrapper altogether.

Without the wrapper, here's 2 different status checks using promises, one for success and one for failure:

```js
describe('Read data from API', () => {
  test('Get successful result of the API call', async() => {
    const apiUrl = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character";
    await axios.get(apiUrl)
      .then(r => {
        expect(r.data).toBeDefined();
        expect(r.data.results.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        expect(r.status).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(200);
        expect(r.status).toBeLessThan(300);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        fail(`Expected successful response`);
      });
  });

  test('Get failure result of the API call', async() => {
    const apiUrl = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character-bad";
    await axios.get(apiUrl)
      .then(r => {
        fail(`Expected failure response`);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        if (e.response) {
          expect(e.response.status).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(400);
          expect(e.response.status).toBeLessThan(500);
        } else {
          throw e;
        }
      });
  });
});
```